# IPSec Site-to-site VPN speed between Germany and China very poor

Tags: performance, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

we have successfully setup a Site-to-site IPSec VPN connection between our two offices in Germany and China. Below are the characteristics of both sites, VPN and current speeds:

**Germany**
VPN Router Zyxel Zywall USG 100
Site's Internet speed: 50/50 Mbps

**VPN Tunnel**
Type: IPSec
Authentication: SHA-1
Encryption: AES-128
MSS Auto

**China**
VPN Router Cisco RV180 Multifunction VPN Firewall
Site's Internet speed: 20/20 Mbps

**Current Speeds**
Ping from Germany to China: 250 - 350 ms
Ping from China to Germany: 250 - 300 ms 
File Transfer speeds between sites: avg. 10KB/s

**Traceroute from Germany to China**
Tracing route to [10.67.8.189] over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1    <1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.67.5.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4   370 ms   366 ms   336 ms  [10.67.8.189]

Trace complete.

As you can see, we have major speed problems, making even Remote Desktop sometimes unusable. Previously, I have used L2TP between these sites and the performance was much better, RDP usable.

Any advice appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Best,

Tom

Comment: 250/300 ms are really high RTT times. Can you edit your post adding traceroute informations?

Comment: I wouldn't discount the great firewall of China interfering with this traffic.

Comment: Will have a lot to do with the carriers you are using at the POP to POP latency as well.

Comment: I hope it's not the Great Firewall. Is there a best practice for site-to-site over the Chinese borders? Perhaps another protocol or encryption?

Answer (score 2):

The speed/throughput may be some *external* factor, as EEAA mentions. But in general, when I've needed to provide remote access across long distance links (Chicago-Hong Kong or London-Seoul), RDP was not an option. Latency kills you at those distances...

Do you have the option to use something that's a bit better with high-latency long-distance links? Citrix (*of course*) and [Ericom Blaze](http://www.ericom.com/ericom_blaze.asp) (and RDP accelerator) come to mind, as they fare much better in the conditions you describe.

Comment: It's not only about RDP. The Office in China is a branch office with child domain, we are replicating 1 domain controller over the link. We need to keep the Offices connected on a acceptable level, at least 60KB/s. L2TP was faster but it's not an option now due to lower security.

Comment: @Tom Hm, so that's why China doesn't mess with L2TP...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, but obviously we can't be transferring data in plain text between our sites.

Comment: I still haven't resolved this. However I must say it's a challenging task to stand against China.